# how to delete empty rows in laravel excel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-excel

So i work with Laravel, and i use Laravel excel to load excel/csv files, but my files contains empty rows and i want to delete every empty row.

this is my code :

```
Excel::selectSheetsByIndex(0)->load($path, function($reader){
       $results = $reader->noHeading()->toArray();
         foreach ($results as $row) {
            //my code
         }
       }, 'UTF-8');
```

So please if someone has any idea how i can do that i will be very appreciative

Comment: Good question. Did you found an answer? I would like to know it ;)

Comment: still no answer :(

Answer (score 2):

I think you can do it in this way

```
/** @var LaravelExcelReader $data */
        $data = \Excel::load('file.xls', function ($reader) {
            $reader->limitRows(20);
            $reader->ignoreEmpty();
        })->get()->toArray();

        # remove empty rows
        $data = array_filter($data);
```

Answer (score 0):

use ToCollection method the wrap everything within `if($row->filter()->isNotEmpty())`

```
    public function collection(Collection $rows)
       {
          foreach($rows as $row) {
            if($row->filter()->isNotEmpty()){
                // you logic can go here

                $user = User::create([
                    'name' => ucwords($row['name']),
                    'class' => $row['class'],
                    ...
                ]);
            }
        }   
       }
```